# Python 3 if statement recognition

Tags: python

The calculator does not recognize the price input being 60 as the first if statement, it will send you to else.

```
while True:
    price = float(input("How much does it cost? (include cents!): $"))
    discount=float(price)*100 / 1000
    discount2=float(price)*200 /1000
    proceed = 60
    proceed2 = 120
    if price >= proceed << proceed2:
        print("Your new cost is")
        print(round(price - discount, 2))
        print("Press any key to exit")
        input()
    if price >= proceed2:
        print("Your new cost is")
        print(round(price - discount, 2))
        print("Press any key to exit")
        input()
    else:
        print("You are not viable for a discount, make a purchase >= sixty dollars to recive a 10% discount or a purchase >= $120 for a 20% discount.")
print("Press any key to exit")
input()
```

Comment: `proceed << proceed2` is not doing what you think it is doing

Comment: please state the problem this code is attempting to solve, not just the problem you are having solving it.

Comment: The problem of this code is based in the equivalence.

Comment: try wrapping price >= proceed in parens

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the first if statement used `<<` when it should have used `<`.

```
while True:
    price = float(input("How much does it cost? (include cents!): $"))
    discount=float(price)*100 / 1000
    discount2=float(price)*200 /1000
    proceed = 60
    proceed2 = 120
    if price >= proceed < proceed2:
        print("Your new cost is")
        print(round(price - discount, 2))
        print("Press any key to exit")
        input()
    if price >= proceed2:
        print("Your new cost is")
        print(round(price - discount, 2))
        print("Press any key to exit")
        input()
    else:
        print("You are not viable for a discount, make a purchase >= sixty dollars to recive a 10% discount or a purchase >= $120 for a 20% discount.")
print("Press any key to exit")
input()
```